# Channel form error with grid file field, comma in file name

Tags: safecracker, file-uploads

I'm running into a problem using Channel Forms on EE 3.4.4 with a file field inside a grid. If the filename contains a comma it will initially submit but subsequent saves return an error message: 'There was a problem with one or more grid fields'.

Everything works as intended through the Control Panel, it only appears to be affecting Channel Forms. As soon a I remove the file with the comma in the name it works perfectly fine.

Has anyone had any similar problems with this at all?

Answer (score 0):

**Caution:**
I've noticed that duplicate files are being added when submitting an entry. I'm not sure whether this is a result of the below or not. First test indicate not but I'd use the below with caution.

I have managed to fixed this problem but its not entirely elegant.

Wherever the file name is being referenced in the 'file field' view file I've added `str_replace` to convert `%2C` to a comma. `<?=str_replace('%2C', ',', $string)?>`

`system/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/View/_shared/file/field.php`

```
<div class="file_field">
    <div class="file_set <?=$set_class?>">

        <p class="filename">
            <img src="<?=$thumb?>" alt="<?=str_replace('%2C', ',', $alt)?>"/> <!-- Optional -->
            <br />
            <?=str_replace('%2C', ',', $filename)?> <!-- Optional -->
            <?=$remove_file_link?>
        </p>
        <p><?=str_replace('%2C', ',', $hidden);?></p> <!-- Required -->
    </div>

    <div class='file_upload'>
        <p class="sub_filename">
            <?=$undo_link?>
            <?=$filebrowser ? $upload_link : ''?>
        </p>

        <div class="no_file <?=($filebrowser || $filename) ? 'js_hide' : ''?>">
            <p class='sub_filename'><?=$upload?></p>
            <?php if ( ! $allowed_file_dirs):?>
                <p><?=$dropdown?></p>
            <?php else: ?>
                <p><?=$directory?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( ! empty($existing_files)) : ?>
                <p class="file_existing"><?=$existing_files?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

I'm not marking this answer as accepted as there is probably a better way to solve this, however, I thought I'd add the answer in case someone else has the issue and needs a temporary fix.